# Django how to retrieve post data from Modelform and static formfields mixed together

Tags: python, django, post, model, modelform

I'm using a Django Modelform mixed with static form fields to generate a HTML form like so:

**Models.py:**

```
class example(models.Model):
    value_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    value_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value_4 = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    value_5 = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    label_1 = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    label_2 = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    label_3 = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ExampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = example
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['label_1','label_2','label_3']
```

**Template (HTML):**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Start static form fields -->
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="label_1" value="blabla">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="label_2" value="blabla">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="label_3" value="blabla">
    <!-- End static form fields -->

    <!-- Start Modelform fields -->
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field|addcss:'form-control' }}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ field.errors }}</span>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3 class="text-warning">Database lookup failed.</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    <!-- End Modelform fields -->

    <button class="btn btn-complete btn-lg" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
</form>
```

The HTML form shows perfectly with the static and the dynamic form fields. I can request the form values and see them like so:

```
form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
return HttpResponse(form)
```

**Problem:**

When I use the above technique to request POST data I only receive the post data from Modelform (dynamic fields) and not the data from the static fields!

I found out I can request the posted values from the static fields this way:

```
label_1 = request.POST.get("label_1")
return HttpResponse(label_1)
```

Above code will give me the value of the posted static checkbox. However, now I have to collect all the static fields and I want to catch all posted data at once and than handle it further.

Now my question, how is it possible that I don't get all the post values when I request them in Django? How do I make 1 variable with all the post data in it including modelform values and static form fields?

Hope my question is clear, thanks guys! :)

Comment: You specifically removed the fields from the form, so of course they're not in the form data. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: Because I add them again manualy again in the HTML form like so <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="label_1" value="blabla">

Comment: Yes. And therefore they are in `request.POST`, as you show. But they can't be in `form.cleaned_data`, because you excluded them. I must say, I don't understand why you are doing this in the first place.

Comment: alright I took the wrong approach.. I'm now calling all the fields "manualy" and I use the modelform, that is working. Sorry for the confusion mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might want to take a close look at this line:

```
    exclude = ['label_1','label_2','label_3']
```

Comment: I don't want the label_1, label_2 and label_3 values to be handled by modelform so that's why I'm excluding them. However, I do add them manualy in my HTML form like so: <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="label_1" value="blabla"> I don't think that my modelform exclude should influence the POST request data that is send from the client to the server? Also my question is how to mix them together so I don't want to work with the modelform only but also with static form fields.

Comment: alright I took the wrong approach.. I'm now calling all the fields "manualy" and I use the modelform, that is working. Sorry for the confusion mate.